# Accidentally Deleted SQL Server Log Reader Service Account

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Uh, I accidentally deleted the Security Login in my SQL server that allows for the reading of log files.

Now, I can no longer see any of the log files in my SQL Server Logs node of SMSS:(

What account is it so that I can add back the login?

I think it started with "BUILT IN" or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I guessed it.  It was "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE".  When I added it back as a login, then the log files showed up after I refreshed the node tree.  (sorry for the noise)